# How to use google cloud storage with vision api

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

Im trying to use vision api to detect  labels on the image but i can't directly use external link  with api.
I want to first  upload the image to google cloud  storage and then use vision  api to detect labels in it.
What is the best way to do it.
I'm  using node js.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the image in google cloud storage, you can reference it for annotation.

See the example for calling Vision API referencing an image in GCS, with nodejs client library: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels#detect_labels_in_a_remote_image